# Подключение сторонней библиотеки в проект Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Какие шаги нужно выполнить, чтобы добавить чужой проект (библиотеку) к своему в Android Studio? Нужно, чтобы я мог обратиться из своего проекта к классам из чужого проекта. В build.gradle я уже прописал.

Comment: проект какого рода: исходные коды, JAR, репозиторий Maven ?

Comment: исходник с github

Comment: Приведите ссылку на github. И что вы написали в build.gradle?

Comment: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer
Это Navigation Drawer в стиле Material Design.
В build.gradle добавил то, что там написано:

`compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:2.9.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}`

Comment: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#using-maven. А дальше там написано после этого. Просто используешь.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Во-первых, если библиотека достаточно выского качества, то автор библиотеки, как правило, дает инструкции о том, как ее подключить в свой проект - им надо следовать в первую очередь.

Сама Android Studio позволяет подключить три типа библиотек в свой проект:

- из репозитория Maven
- библиотеку в виде собранного .jar файла
- библиотеку в виде исходных кодов

Для выполнения этой работы в Android Studio есть графический интерфейс, но олдскульные кодеры могут проделать ту же работу, прописывая необходимые команды в конфиги `gradle` вручную.
Открываем окно структуры проекта (`File -> Project Structure`) и переходим к основному модулю проекта - слева секция *Modules*, кликнуть по названию модуля вашего приложения (на скриншоте это *app*). В открывшемся окне переходим к вкладке `Dependencies`.  Здесь вы можете управлять подключенными зависимостями: добавить новые, удалить ненужные и перемещать их по иерархии.

[image: Структура проекта]

Для того, чтобы добавить зависимость, нажимаем на `плюсик` справа и видим три пункта - рассмотрим их подробнее:

1. **Library dependency — добавление библиотеки из внешнего репозитория**

Этот пункт требует, как правило, наименьшего количества усилий. Обычно, по умолчанию, в конфиге `gradle` всего проекта в качестве внешнего репозитория используется `JCenter` и все уважающие себя разработчики складывают свои труды туда, но вы можете прописать в том конфиге и другие репозитории с библиотеками, если таковые вам требуются.
При выборе пункта 1 появляется окно поиска, в котором вы можете набрать имя требуемой библиотеки и, если она присутствует в репозитории - вы ее увидите. Нажатие кнопки `OK` проделает всю черную работу по подключению библиотеки и после того, как `gradle` проведет необходимые манипуляции по скачиванию и импорту, она будет доступна в вашем проекте.

[image: Выбор зависимых библиотек]

Если вы не доверяете инструментам Android Studio и желаете самостоятельно вручную добавить библиотеку из репозитория, вам необходимо прописать в секции `dependencies{}` конфига `build.gradle` вашего приложения ссылку на нужную библиотеку:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:2.9.8'
 }
```

При внесении каких-либо изменений в конфиги `gradle` вверху появляется предупреждение о необходимости синхронизировать проект - когда все изменения будут сделаны, нажмите на ссылку `Sync Now` вверху справа, чтобы `gradle` применил ваши изменения.

2. **File dependency — добавление библиотеки из локального скомпилированного .jar файла**

Перед началом импорта локальной библиотеки в виде .jar файла необходимо скопировать сам файл библиотеки в папку `/libs` вашего проекта.
При выборе пункта 2 появится стандартный диалог выбора файла, в котором необходимо указать, собственно, сам файл подключаемой библиотеки.
При нажатии кнопки `OK` `gradle` проведет некоторые манипуляции по импорту, которые займут какое-то время, после чего библиотека будет доступна в вашем проекте.

[image: Выбор пути]

Для того, чтобы вручную сделать то же самое — добавить библиотеку на основе .jar файла, в секции `dependencies{}` конфига `build.gradle` приложения необходимо прописать следующее:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/realm.jar')
}
```

Для того, чтобы подключить все библиотеки из папки `/libs/` разом, нужно сделать так:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

3. **Module dependency — добавление библиотеки из исходных кодов**

Перед импортом библиотеки из исходных кодов необходимо скачать сами исходные коды и распаковать в какой-то каталог.
Для наименьших проблем:

- исходные коды должны быть `gradle-проектом` `Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA`
- имена основного модуля и модуля подключаемой библиотеки не должны совпадать.
- подключаемый исходник является библиотекой, а не приложением (в `build.gradle` того, что вы подключаете указано `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`) — это можно исправить самостоятельно в конфиге `gradle` того, что вы подключаете.
- минимальные версии `SDK` вашего проекта и библиотеки должны совпадать — можно исправить самостоятельно в конфигах `gradle` проекта или библиотеки.
- версии `BuildTools` проекта и библиотеки должны совпадать (рекомендуется), либо обе версии должны быть установлены в вашем `SDK` **(не рекомендуется)**. Лучшее решение — всегда использовать самую последнюю версию `BuildTools`

Для начала импортируем нужную библиотеку в свой проект в качестве модуля. Нажимаем `File -> New -> Import Module`, указываем путь до корневой папки с разархивированными исходниками и следуем другим указаниям мастера импорта.

[image: Меню импорта модуля]

После чего, выбрав пункт 3 (смотрите первый скриншот) появляется окно выбора модуля, кликнув по нужному и нажав кнопку `OK` будет проведена работа по импорту в ваш проект, после чего библиотека будет доступна в вашем проекте.

Добавление библиотеки на основе исходников вручную — несколько муторное занятие и описывать я его не буду. Ценители ручного способа конфигурации проекта получат удовольствие, проделав "таинство" самостоятельно, а остальным вовсе без надобности.

Comment: теперь всё понятно. Значит нужная мне библиотека просто находилась в репозитории Maven. :)

Comment: @compl  Это то же самое, что в ручную прописать `compile <библиотека>` в секцию `dependencies {}` в файле `build.gradle` модуля, только через GUI. Просто в данном случае студия сама добавляет эти строчки в конфиг - если вы его посмотрите, то увидите их там.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#minimal-setup

> It's (theoretically) a one-liner :D. This will create an empty drawer.

```
new Drawer().withActivity(this).build()
```

### Activity with Toolbar

```
Drawer.Result result = new Drawer()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withToolbar(toolbar)
    .addDrawerItems(
        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home),
        new DividerDrawerItem(),
        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings)
    )
    .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
        // do something with the clicked item :D
    }
    })
    .build();

//use the result object to get different views of the drawer or modify it's data
//some sample calls
result.setSelectionByIdentifier(1);
result.openDrawer();
result.closeDrawer();
result.isDrawerOpen();
result.addItem(..);
..
```

Ну там же все написано...

Comment: Спасибо. Но не в этом проблема была. У меня не хотела студия импортировать `Drawer`. И я подумал, что всю эту библиотеку нужно как-то в свой проект добавлять. И, кстати, каким образом студия импортировала эту библиотеку? Она весь комп сканирует или что? (папка с библиотекой лежит просто на рабочем столе) :)

Comment: @compl При импорте библиотеки через зависимости `gradle` она скачивается в кэш-папку самого `gradle` . По умолчанию это каталог:  `C:\Users\<User Name>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\ ` и студия не сканирует весь комп, `gradle` хранит локальную ссылку на импортированную библиотеку в своих конфигах.

Comment: Например в `eclipse`: Project>Libs>Add lib... И указываешь путь.