# Как в IntellijIDEA 14 обновить *-sources.jar?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Доброго времени!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что к `jackson-databind-2.0.2.jar` были добавлены исходники другой версии `jackson-databind-2.1.1-sources.jar`. Попытался исправить ситуацию, загрузил подходящие, но никак не могу понять как их теперь скормить IDEA.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144468/re-attach-sources-in-intellij

Нашел эту ссылку, но "Libraries" у меня почти пустая, и вышеупомянутый пакет там не значится (вобще там кроме Grails 2.4.4 ничего нет).

Есть у кого опыт на данном поприще?

Comment: вот почитайте о подключении библиотек в IDEA/AS ( в частности пункт 3) - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя в либрари этого пакета нет, значит у тебя не подключена эта библиотека. Подключи библиотеку и назначь исходники

Comment: Формально не подключена. Но каким образом я тогда смог приатачить к пакету исходные коды? Все *.jar валяются в ~/.m2/repository. Это получается мне каждый *.jar нужно вручную добавить?

Comment: Ну так скачай их через мавен.  Скачай через 1 ответ, а если будут ошибки - посмотри последний ответ