# Импортировать библиотеку jLayer в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

Как импортировать  [эту библиотеку](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) в `Android Studio`?
Испробовал: переносил .jar-файл в папку libs с проектор, после чего ПКМ и `Add as library...`. При разработке видит все библиотеки, но после запуска проекта выдает ошибку `no main manifest attribute`.

Comment: Добавьте конкретики. Что за либа, что вы пробовали, что из опробованного у вас не получилось. И метку про `android` добавьте - а то вопрос никто не увидит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О подключении всех типов библиотек в Android Studio смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345).

Вы можете посмотреть [исходники проекта AudioTrackMp3Player](https://github.com/Cookizz/AudioTrackMp3Player), где эта библиотека используется, думаю это вам хорошо поможет.

Кроме того, есть [версия библиотеки jlayer-android-decoder](https://github.com/tlantz/jlayer-android-decoder), адаптированная под Android SDK