# Как подключить библиотеку в коде android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, библиотеки

Здравствуйте, я хочу подключить [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar) в *Android Studio*, но не понимаю как ее подключить и использовать в коде?
Я уже пробовал через *File->Project Structure->Dependencies*, но так и не разобрался.

Comment: пробовал по [этому](https://habrahabr.ru/post/183846/?mobile=no) туториалу но он все усложняет.

Comment: Тут говорят знающие люди, что лучше подключать в качестве модуля - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425567/Подключение-сторонней-библиотеки-в-проект-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В своем проекте создаете пакет `com.pascalwelsch.holocircularprogressbar`
2. В этом пакете создаете java-класс `HoloCircularProgressBar.java`.
3. Из папки `library`  копируете содержимое файла `HoloCircularProgressBar.java`  и вставляете в ваш файл. Смотрите, чтобы package был указан только 1 раз. Будет ругаться, что "cannot resolve symbol r". Надо импортировать этот самый r (`Alt+Enter` в Android Studio) и rebuild project
4. Из папки res проекта на гитхаб копируем `attrs.xml` (создав его, если нет) и `styles.xml` (добавив его содержимое в соответствующий свой файл)
5. Пример использования желанного виджета смотрим в `CircularProgressBarSample` (папка `sample/src/com...`)

Можно было бы создать основной файл и  в своем основном пакете, но тогда к нему надо будет по-другому обращаться (не как в примере использования)

Comment: На мой взгляд это очень неудачный способ подключения библиотек к проекту. А что если там больше 1 файла? А что если библиотека обновится? Правильным способом подключения в данном случае будет являться подключение библиотеки как модуля.

Comment: Так объясните человеку как это сделать. Я тоже поучусь с радостью.

Comment: Смотрите комментарий под вопросов про дубликат

Comment: @temq Это мой комментарий. По вашей наводке я нашла эту ссылку. Спасибо)

Comment: Я имел ввиду комментарий @pavlofff

Answer (score 3):

Закидываете файлы библиотеки .jar в каталог проекта в папку `app/libs`, дальше в  `File->Project Structure->Dependencies` плюсик `file dependency` и добавляете .jar файл библиотеки

Comment: В этом та и проблема все говорят о .jar файлах а у меня проект библиотеки.