# Указать путь к библиотеке

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В инструкции для разработчиков *Eclipse* сказано:

> Выберите в списке опций Java Build Path, затем в открывшемся окне
>   перейдите на вкладку Libraries. Нажмите кнопку “Add JARs…” и укажите
>   путь к скачанной библиотеке ..._android.jar.

Вопрос заключается в том, как эту операцию реализовать в android studio?

Comment: В дереве каталога последним элементом есть пункт экстернал либрариес. Кликнишь на него укажешь путь и все пучком.

Comment: В вкладке Project?

Comment: Да прям в редакторе кода в левой части он есть. Да вроде проэкт. Ну и в файл->дефаулт сеттингс  можете настройть.

Comment: А где расположен  дефаулт сеттингс ?

Comment: В меню фаил редактора. В общем то более подробно в этом посте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507207/191902