# Использование сторонней библиотеки. Inflate Exception

Tags: android, xml, gradle

Пытаюсь воспользоваться кастомным календарем. (вывести его в стандартном виде через xml-разметку). Но приложение крашится. В чем может быть причина?
Все сделал как сказано [здесь](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View). Делал через Gradle вручную вставляя в `build.gradle`. Эта же проблема и с другими подобными библиотеками, перепробовал уже штук 5-6.

В блоке `dependencies` в файле `build.gradle` который лежит в корне папки app, ссылка на гит:

```
compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0'
```

в глобальном `build.gradle`, в том который лежит в корне проекта:

```
maven{url "jitpack.io";}
```

Попытка использовать библиотеку в Java-коде выкидывает Inflate Exception.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.denis.myplans.NewNoteActivity">

<com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

лог ошибки:

> Process: com.example.denis.myplans, PID: 661
>                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.denis.myplans/com.example.denis.myplans.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                                          at com.example.denis.myplans.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112)
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                                          at com.example.denis.myplans.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; regionStart=0; regionLength=3
>                                                                          at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
>                                                                          at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)
>                                                                          at com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView.initializeWeekLayout(CustomCalendarView.java:171)
>                                                                          at com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView.refreshCalendar(CustomCalendarView.java:356)
>                                                                          at com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView.initializeCalendar(CustomCalendarView.java:132)
>                                                                          at com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView.(CustomCalendarView.java:74)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                                          at com.example.denis.myplans.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>   4   в текст добавлено 4811 символов

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.denis.myplans;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.imanoweb.calendarview.CustomCalendarView; //вот импорт класса

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        CustomCalendarView calendarView = (CustomCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view); //вот создание объекта 

        calendarView.setFirstDayOfWeek(4);// вот сюда ругает NullPointerExeption
        final Intent intNewNote = new Intent(this, NewNoteActivity.class);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        assert fab != null;

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(intNewNote);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Покажите целиком разметку и укажите точный тип ошибки и лог

Comment: проблемы со вставкой кода на сайте... не отображается
то что в вопросе просто обернуто в стандартный relativelayout

Comment: Код должен иметь отступ в 4 пробела слева. Можно его целиком выделить и нажать на фигурные скобки вверху редактора - отступы сами появятся.

Comment: Судя по стэку проблема при вызове вьюшке календаря. Толи передаваемый id плох, толи найти не может, толи еще что-то

Comment: а если забыть про джаву и стек трейс... почему я не могу подключить вообще какую либо стороннюю библиотеку? ведь оно не пашет даже просто xml разметку вывести.

Comment: где располагается gradle файл? и пример того, как происходит подключение

Comment: все так как описано по ссылке... В блоке dependencies в файле build.gradle который лежит в корне папки app, ссылка на гит - compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0' 
а в глобальном build.gradle, в том который лежит в корне проекта, в блоке maven{url "https://jitpack.io"} короче все сделал как там

Comment: Вы можете в своем проекте создать экземпляр класса `CustomCalendarView` из кода, никаких ошибок не появляется? И вы определитесь, что у вас за ошибка `NullPointerExeption` или `InflateExeption`. Не исправляйте вопрос так, чтобы первоначальный смысл был утерян, если нашли решение проблемы - оформите ответом и задайте новый вопрос по новой проблеме.

Comment: Попробуйте подключить библиотеку как модуль: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425567/Подключение-сторонней-библиотеки-в-проект-android-studio.