# Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем, привет!

Установил Android Studio на машину где нет интернета (обновить код через SDK Manager нет возможности)

Создал новый проект и ...  красным подсветились все классы. Сообщения об ошибках выглядят таким образом:

```
cannot resolve symbol "AppCompatActivity"
```

`File->InvalidateCahces` и `Build->Clean Project` не помогают.

в dependencies стоит:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
```

как решить проблему?

Спаcибо.

Comment: А build.gradle у вас сихнронизировался после добавления зависимости appcompat?

Comment: @Werder , нет  `Grable project sync failed...`

Comment: тогда ответ BORSHEVIK как раз для вас

Answer (score 4):

"Установил Android Studio на машину где нет интернета" Очевидно, что нужно подключить интернет, ибо строка compile `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"` гикорит Gradle, чтобы тот скачал эту библиотеку и скомпилировал, а как вы это собираетесь сделать, если интернета нету. Можно решить и иначе, вы скачиваете где-нибудь AppCompact либу и добавляете её в свой проект в качестве библиотеки, т.е. имортите не через gradle, а как файл, чтобы он был у вас виден как проект, далее в gradle добавить строку на подобие этой `compile project(":Имя вашего проекта-библиотеки")`

Comment: есть ли отдельный репозитарий, где можно скачать эту либу без SDK Manager, как файл?

Comment: кажется нашел https://github.com/koush/android-support-v7-appcompat/tree/master/libs  ,как ее подключить?

Comment: @ravend Качаете нужный вам Jar файл, далее в Android Strudio (У меня версия 1.4) File->New->New Module->Import .JAR/ .AAR Package , далее в File name нужно указать путь к .JAR файлу, если после выбора Jar файла поле Subproject name не будет заполнено, то заполните его любым именем по вкусу

Comment: @ravend библиотек гугла нет на гитхабе - все, что там есть, какие то форки. Они есть в репозиториях [Maven/JCenter](https://bintray.com/lukar1203/maven/appcompat-v7/view) и на серверах самого гугла.

Comment: @pavlofff , есть ли возможность экспорта этой библиотеки с другой машины (где есть интернет), если да то как это сделать?

Comment: @ravend Вот этот https://github.com/koush/android-support-v7-appcompat проект качните и подключите в Android студи, как модуль, но не Jar

Comment: @BORSHEVIK , скачал *.aar, подключил его как Вы описали выше (через New Module->Import ...), в проекте появилась пустая ветка по названию модуля. Ошибки не исчезли. Clean Project и Sync делал. Попробовал поменять версии в build.grable, ничего не изменилось. Есть еще идеи?

Comment: @ravend Скорее всего это связано с тем, что данного класса AppCompatActivity просто нету в той либе с гита. Вам повезло, я нашёл проект с гита с либами разных версий, качайте его, там нужный класс уже точно есть https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support. Из этого репа вам нужна папка V7, вот её и подключайте

Comment: @BORSHEVIK , а как ее подключать? пробую по инструкции из этого топика: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425567/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-android-studio   Делаю, File->New->Import Module: выбираю путь к папке V7, OK. Пишет `Specify location of the Grable or Android Eclipse project`

Comment: @BORSHEVIK , подключил v7/appcompat, потянулись зависимости с v4. В File->Project Structures->Dependencies добавил и `v4`, и `appcompat`. Теперь ошибка в `v4/build.grable`  `Gradle DSL method not found: 'getAndroidPrebuilt()'`

Comment: @ravend А зачем вы v4 подтягиваете, вам только v7 нужна

Comment: @BORSHEVIK , я так понимаю v7 просит v4. В `appcompat/build.grable` стоит `dependencies { compile project(':support-v4') ... }` и оно ругается `Project with path ':support-v4' could not be found in project ':appcompat'`

Comment: @ravend Попробуйте тогда подгрузить не только v7, а папку целиком, которая содержит в себе и v7 и v4

Comment: @BORSHEVIK , добавил v4, он потянул `annotations`, добавил и его, теперь от `annotations\build.gradle` висит ошибка `Gradle DSL method not found: 'mavenDeployer()'`