# Что сделать, чтоб добавить библиотеку support:design?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library

Создал новый проект чтоб попробовать поработать с библиотекой `support:design` добавил

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

в зависимости и все заработало.

Решил добавить тоже самое в основной проект и мне показало ошибку, я посмотрел и понял, что проблема в том, что версия

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

выше чем в библиотеке

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

я посмотрел, что мой

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

и решил поставить версию библиотеки тоже такую и стало выглядеть это так

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.2'
```

Вот так в итоге выглядит мой билд

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile files('libs/svgandroid.jar')
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile files('libs/guava-16.0.1.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
    'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
    'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
    'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        dirs.each { dir ->
            java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
            res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
        }
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
}
}
```

при билде получит вот такое окно

[image: окно 1]

Естественно нажал `Install Repository and syns` и получил такое окно

[image: окно 2]

Вроде как интернета не хватает, хотя интернет работает отлично.

Пробовал менять версию этой библиотеки на разные и каждый раз разные ошибки...

**Что нужно сделать, чтоб это работало?**

Я по пробовал разные версии вот, что получается когда подключаю

```
'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

Какие то ресурсы уже определены и показывает ошибку.. Что это значит?

[image: окно 3]

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что существует версия библиотеки 23.0.2? Перестаньте привязывать версию build tools к версии библиотеки, они совершенно не зависят друг от друга.

Comment: @metalurgus мне так показалось))

Comment: @metalurgus Только, что заметил, что в проекте после добавления этой библиотеки начинает подсвечивать красным класс R ... Почему то проект перестает его видеть... Если убираю библиотеку то все начинает работать...

Answer (score 1):

Укажите

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

как минимум версия `design` совпадает с другими версиями от `com.android.support`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

**UPD** обновите также

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21 // укажите акутальную старую API которую будете поддерживать
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
```

и всем остальным библиотекам `com.android.support` укажите версию **23.3.0**

Comment: Добавил описание... Я пробовал разные версии ставить и всегда что то вываливалось... вот и сейчас тоже... Как быть?

Comment: Только, что заметил, что в проекте после добавления этой библиотеки начинает подсвечивать красным класс R ... Почему то проект перестает его видеть... Если убираю библиотеку то все начинает работать...

Comment: При синхронизации gradle удаляется build папка, по этому у вас идет подсветка

Comment: Так minSdkVersion 21 это правильно... Приложение не будет работать в версиями ниже Lolipop

Comment: Насчет R понял... Пока градл не закончит выполнение папка не создается... А по скольку при градл ошибка, то онп и остается не созданой... Верно?

Comment: Есть зависимость targetSdkVersion и версия com.android.support если указали sdk 22 то библиотека должна иметь такуюже версию, com.android.support:22.х.х, для targetSdkVersion 23 соотвественно com.android.support:23.х.х, так же указывайте одинаковую версию support для всех библиотек.

Comment: по поводу R, так как попка удалена, она не создается так как Gradle не может подсасать библиотеку, соотвественно до компиляции не доходит. а по сколько R файл не создан, проект будет светится. Не пугайтесь это нормально )

Comment: С R класс понял

Comment: Вот, что получилось в итоге, я поменял все библиотеки без добавления дизайн lib скомпилировал все работает, добавил дизайн lib и опять вывалилась ошибка как в описании...

Comment: svg-android.jar  - как минимум можно убрать одну (задвоение) так и вторую, так как есть уже нативная поддержка векторов. support-v4, support-v13 (они для поддержки Pre Lollipop) как минимум не нужны. play-services - опять задвоение, приведите в порядок, и все соберется

Comment: Обновил в описании градл, все почистил, но все равно как только добавляю lib `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'` все крашится.... Каждый раз пишет, что Error:(178) Attribute "borderWidth" has already been defined, может найти это атрибут и удалить его? Или так нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

В *Google Support Library* не было никакой версии 23.0.2, поэтому вы и получаете ошибку.

Вы можете ознакомится с номерами версий вышедших библиотек поддержки, например, [здесь](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions).

А лучше добавлять зависимости через мастер (вариант №1 [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345)), а не вручную. Он не даст вам совершить подобной вещи.

Comment: Да я пробовал найти этот мастер, но сейчас там поменялся интерфейс и там нет вкладки добавить зависимость... Когда нажимаю на + он предлагает много всего но там тоже нет добавить зависимость... Когда нажимаю добавить библиотеку андроид он просто создает новую библиотеку и просит назвать ее именем

Comment: Только, что заметил, что в проекте после добавления этой библиотеки начинает подсвечивать красным класс R ... Почему то проект перестает его видеть... Если убираю библиотеку то все начинает работать...

Comment: В общем не в этом дело...(

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Не знаю, где вы там что пробовали найти и какие у вас интерфейсы кто поменял, но уверяю, что и на самой последней версии AS 2.1 все мастера  *Project Structure* остались в прежнем виде.

Comment: Следуя примеру я нажимаю  `File - Project Structure` и вот, что у меня открывается https://dropmefiles.com/aSM28   . Может действительно у меня как то изменен интерфейс...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Если вы внимательно посмотрите на скриншоты в инструкции, то увидите, что нужно нажать на модуль вашего проекта ( в вашем случае это *app* в секции *Modules* в самом низу слева) там вы и увидите все нужные вкладки. Дополню этот момент в инструкции словами, раз возможны непонимания.