# Как редактировать код в загруженных библиотеках?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-library

Здравствуйте, я загрузил библиотеку

compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'

и в ней есть баг, мне надо его пофиксить. Но я не могу вносить правки в проект, он закрыт для редактирования.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста помогите!

Answer (score 5):

Просто так вносить изменения в подключаемую через jar библиотеку нельзя. Для того, чтобы исправить баг клонируйте репозиторий с проектом к себе на машину, подключайте как локальный модуль и тогда уже вносите изменения в нее.

Если вы используете у себя в проекте систему контроля версий `git`, то легче всего подключить библиотеку как [подмодуль](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8). Для этого:

1. В командной строке переходите в коталог со своим проектом;
2. Выполняете команду `git submodule add git://github.com/path_to_lib`;
3. В корневом файле `settings.gradle` добавляете ее так `include ':libName'`;
4. В `build.gradle` модуля приложения добавляете так `compile project(':LibName:library')`.

После этого вы можете вносить изменения в библиотеку, которые потом будут отображены в вашем проекте. После чего вы легко сможете отправить `pull request` автору библиотеки с фиксом бага.

Про то, как работать с подмодулями в гит, и как они себе ведут при коммите прочтите на официальном сайте(ссылка выше).

Answer (score 3):

1. Вбейте в гугл пакет библиотеки.
2. По первой ссылке перейдите на страницу либы на GitHub-e
3. Скачайте библиотеку как набор исходных файлов в архиве.
4. Распакуйте архив.
5. Откройте код в IDE
6. Отредактируйте.
7. Соберите `*.jar` файл библиотеки (опционально)
8. Подключите исправленную версию библиотеки или с помощью файла из п.7 или добавьте проект с библиотекой в виде зависимости.

Comment: на самом деле можно попытаться это сделать без исходников (мало ли недоступны к примеру). Можно аккуратно отнаследоваться, а можно извлечь проблемный класс из библиотеки и добавить свой с таким же пакетом.

Comment: @pavel, тоже вариант, кто-то уже в другом ответе об этом написал)

Answer (score 3):

Вы не можете изменять уже собранные библиотеки (строго говоря можете, но это плохой и сложный путь). Вы можете либо отнаследоваться от проблемного класса, исправить поведение в наследнике и использовать его если косяк не слишком глубокий. Либо если это open source библиотека форкуть её, исправить и либо отправить пулл реквест с исправлением автору оригинальной библиотеки что бы он включил его в свой репозиторий и обновил библиотеку, либо собрать свою реализацию и использовать её в своём проекте.

Answer (score 3):

При подключении библиотеки способом, который у вас в вопросе, вы получаете скомпилированный файл, который нельзя редактировать.

Для решения вашей проблемы вам нужно [подключить данную библиотеку в виде исходных кодов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345) (пункт 3 ответа), если разработчик предоставляет такой формат распространения своей библиотеки (исходники) и внести исправления в своей локальной копии, либо, что предпочтительнее и правильнее, писать ему багрепорт, чтобы он исправил баг в новой версии своей библиотеки и использовать ее.