# не подключается Jar библиотека. Глюк андроид студио

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Подключаю библиотеку Asne через library depency, библиотека есть в хранилище и нормально функционирует. Качаю с интернета исходники этой библиотеки в jar, подключаю, в build-gradle все зависимости появляются, но библиотека либо вообще не подключается, либо при ручном импорте видно,что иерархия папок библиотеки видна, но файлов в ней как будто нет. Единожды мне помогла очистка кэша. (я это делал в экспериментальном проекте) после попробовал в рабочем проекте , но не вышло. Попробовал еще раз в экспер. проекте и тоже не вышло. Делал очистку проект и пересборку проекта. обновил студию до последней стабильной версии и gradle обновил. Не помогает .

Вот залил видео с экрана https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4BMtofYFXI

Попробовал  jar файл библиотеки AndEngine точно так же подключить. Все классы библиотеки нормально импортируются. Может что то не так с самим исходником библиотеки ANSE ? Я вот отсюда их скачал http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Casne

А так же пробовал jar файл который кэшируется когда через library depency подключаю. Файлы идиентичны, результат один и тот же.

Мне нужна эта библиотека в jar для того чтобы вносить изменения в неё.

Чем отличается библиотека в таком виде: https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE от jar библиотеки ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.file"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/asne-vk-0.3.3.3-sources.jar')
}
```

Comment: лучше вместо видео добавить [mcve]

Comment: Ну я добавил. ссылку на jar библиотеку что я подключаю. Попробуйте её себе подключить, сможете ли вы импортировать ее классы в проект ?

Comment: вы не добавили ссылку на пример. и у вас очень общий вопрос.

Comment: Есть ссылка на библиотеку, которая у меня не работает как надо http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/asne/asne-vk/0.3.3.3/asne-vk-0.3.3.3-sources.jar

Comment: Куда еще ближе к примеру то . В никакой проект эта библиотека у меня не подключается. Может косяк в ней самой

Comment: возможно вы ее подключаете не правильно. добавьте `build.gradle`

Comment: добавил , но что тяжелого её подключить. Кинул в папку libs и нажал на библиотеке add as library и он нормально прописывается в build.gradle

Comment: Если подключить так , то она работает compile 'com.github.asne:asne-vk:0.3.3.3'

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, у вас разве работает этот jar? http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/asne/asne-vk/0.3.3.3/asne-vk-0.3.3.3-sources.jar

Comment: исходники библиотеки надо распаковать и подключать [третьим способом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы подключаете не правильный **jar**. Файлы типа ***sources.jar** содержат в себе исходный код, а не откомпилированные class-файлы.

Зависимость типа **compile** ожидает, что внутри **jar** будут class-файлы, а там только java-файлы. Поэтому в IDE ничего не показывается.

Скачайте aar-файл [asne-vk-0.3.3.3.aar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/asne/asne-vk/0.3.3.3/asne-vk-0.3.3.3.aar), положите его в **libs** и добавьте

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'asne-vk-0.3.3.3', ext:'aar')
}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Либо вы можете просто распаковать [asne-vk-0.3.3.3-sources.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/asne/asne-vk/0.3.3.3/asne-vk-0.3.3.3-sources.jar), взять java-файлы из него и положить их в свой проект. Только проверьте, что этим действиями вы не нарушаете лицензию на эту библиотеку.

Comment: Лицензию? А что будет?

Comment: А зачем тогда нужен этот jar ? Ведь когда эту же библиотеку подключаю через maven ,в кэш подгружается тот же самый jar . Я заметил что студия этот jar компилирует,  создает в проекте (не заметил в какой директории) class файлы и использует их.  Как же повторить это, чтобы у меня так же в подключенных библиотеках лежал исходный код для наглядности и использовались его class файлы уже единожды скомпилированные из исходника в момент подключения?

Comment: @Flippy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149355/what-happens-to-those-who-break-open-source-license

Comment: @Turalllb удалось исправить проблему?

Comment: Я дежурю сутки через двое, доступа к компу нет. скоро займусь , отпишусь

Comment: aar библиотеку получилось подключить, но есть проблемы.  В этом архиве есть jar файл в котором и хранится код в class файлах. Чтобы их править надо открыть jar, но в виндовс открыв   aar архив следующим кликом открывать лежащий jar не получается, программой для открытия jar установлена Java машина, а не архиватор. Можно наверно в системе это изменить, но это неудобства. Куда проще из jar все java файлы к себе в проект скопировать

Comment: @Turalllb а зачем вам надо открывать файл в проводнике?

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, не уверен поняли ли вы проблему. Мне без разницы где файл открывать, лишь бы не приходилось каждый раз архив распаковывать, открывать , изменять и снова запаковывать. А aar файл приходится распаковывать, чтобы открыть архиватором jar ,который внутри aar архива лежит и напрямую ,открыв aar и там же следом открыть jar не получается. В общем не суть. главная проблема решена. У меня есть под рукой все java файлы, как закончу их править соберу их снова в библиотеку и всё.

Comment: вот это решение вашей проблемы https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/composite_builds.html

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, вы сказали мне, что я могу  распаковать  asne-vk-0.3.3.3-sources.jar и положить java файлы к себе в проект. Если глянуть asne-vk-0.3.3.3-sources.aar , то внутри него есть куча папок с ресурсами, благо в данном случае они пустые. И в коде естественно нет ссылок на эти ресурсы. Но эта библиотека опирается на vksdk, которая подгружается и отображается в External Librares , при подключении compile 'com.github.asne:asne-vk:0.3.3.3'  . И код этой библиотеки мне тоже нужно править.

Comment: Я так же беру jar файл , но в нем есть ссылки на ресурсы , которые есть только в  aar файле и из-за отсутствия этих ресурсов не формируется R.class для данной библиотеки и все ссылки типа R.id.vk_capcha подчеркнуты красным. Подключить то ,что есть в aar как модуль не получается , ибо это не gradle проект. Так как же его аккуратно подключить к проекту , чтобы можно было править код ?