# Как сделать библиотеку в в виде jar?

Tags: java, android

Есть многим известный компонент PhotoView. К проекту его подключил и проверил работоспособность.
Он состоит из нескольких файлов и папок.

А можно ли из этого всего сделать один файл jar, чтобы его одного подключать к проекту?

Comment: Вам нужен принципиально локальный JAR в проекте? Почему не подключить зависимость через репозиторий и само все скачается. Варианты [подключения внешних](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345) библиотек в Android Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При желании, конечно, можно (`File -> New Module -> Java Library`), только это не самый продуктивный подход, который оправдан скорее для исключительных случаев.

Лучше подключать внешние компоненты через Gradle.

Comment: А можно пример? Как через Gradle это делается. Насколько я понимаю надо создать что-то, а потом подключить это что-то. В каком виде это все?

Comment: @kaaa мне кажется, про это лучше задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @kaaa а вообще алгоритм такой: 1) находите библиотеку на гитхабе 2) читаете ридми. Работает с большинством библиотек. Например: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView#dependency

Comment: Да, наверно так и буду делать. Спасибо.