# Вопрос по азам Android Studio, как создать новый xml

Tags: android-studio

Всем привет!
Учу андроид разработку по разным ресурсам, типа startandroid.
Так вот, я встаю курсором на layout в паке res, правая кнопка мыши ->
new -> android resourse file. См. картинку,  пишу название нового файла.

Студия создает новый xml файл, но проблема в том, что он пустой(текст версия) и вставить в графическое представление что-либо не получается !?

Гуглил не помогло...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что, если вместо `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` в строку *Root element* написать, например `LinearLayout` ? Сама библиотека `СonstraintLayout` у вас добавлена в зависимости проекта? Что значит "пустой" - вообще ничего нет?

Comment: Спасибо, вроде как разобрался.
Вопрос, зависимости проекта что это, если не затруднит , где об этом почитать?

Comment: Зависимости - [добавление (подключение) внешних библиотек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345) в свой проект. Но конкретно `ConstraintLayout` подключается через SDK Manager в Android Studio (должна быть отмечена галка)

Comment: спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Добавил часть скрина с андроид студии. думаю все станет понятно 
[image: Скрин студии]