# класс ContextCompat

Tags: android, permissions

Необходимо объявить [разрешения в runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request).
Однако androidStudio тупо не знает о существовании класса ContextCompat. Что необходимо сделать, что бы он его увидел?

Comment: этот класс входит в библиотеку поддержки support v4 (или AppCompat, в которую в свою очередь входит support v4), насколько можно судить. Эту библиотеку надо подключить в проект.

Comment: @pavlofff через что это делать в android studio?

Comment: @RodGers, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/11515

Answer (score 0):

Убедись, что у тебя стоит стабильная core версия в градл. Андроид указывает её как 1.12.0
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core

Если у тебя многомодульное приложение, то убедись, что ты прокидываешь android dependencies в свой модуль