# android - Что означает число 22 в appcompat-v7:22.2.1?

Tags: android, gradle

Что означает число 22 в файл **build.gradle** - com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**22**.2.1?

Часть файла **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Эм. Номер ревизии? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

22 - мажорная версия библиотеки поддержки (ревизия).

Как правило, совпадает с MAX API Level самого фреймворка Android, вместе с которым используется.

То есть, ревизия библиотеки поддержки 22  используется с максимальным API 22 (на устройствах не новее Android 5.1 Lolipop). 
В проекте имеет смысл использовать самую последнюю релизную версию библиотек поддержки (сейчас 27)

Вы можете вручную указать [любую **существующую** ревизию](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) библиотеки поддержки, отредактировав файл *build.gradle* (последняя релизная сейчас 27.1.1):

```
// для Gradle версии меньше 3.0.0
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' 

// для Gradle версии больше 3.0.0
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

PS: на самом деле версия библиотеки поддержки не может быть ниже значения `compileSDKversion` проекта.

или воспользоваться [графическим интерфейсом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345) Android Studio (тогда студия предложит последнюю доступную версию)

Так же Android Studio дает уведомление, если доступна более новая версия (выделяет строку цветом):

[image: screen]

нажав на "лампочку" слева, вы можете изменить версию  (пункт *Change to [version]* в меню)

Comment: А как обновить библиотеку до версии 27? Заранее спасибо.