# Как подключить библиотеку из GitHub в проект на Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, github

Мне нужно подключить эту библиотеку https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy в проект, который я делаю на Android Studio

Comment: в описании библиотеки написано, как [ее подключить](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/blob/master/README.md#dependency). Общая инструкция [по подключению библиотек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле build.gragle (Module: app) в разделе dependencies добавь строку

```
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
```

И готово!

Comment: В действительности получилось немного не так, нужно прописать вот эти строки: 

   implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'

    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

Но всё равно спасибо огромное за ответ, Вы направили меня по верному пути)