# Как использовать библиотеку из GitHub в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, lib

недавно начал изучать андроид разработку с Java. И пришел к тому, что надо написать маленькую программку(для практики). В проекте хотел сделать боковое меню и по совету нашел отличную библиотеку [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).
Я попытался импортировать библиотеку как мне сказал гугл, думаю понятно то, что у меня не получилось(да и туториал был старый какой-то). Вот у меня вопрос, **как импортировать(использовать) библиотеку из Github в свой(ем) Android проект(е)?**

P.S. *Если возможно оставьте пожалуйста пошаговую инструкцию* 
P.S.S. *Использую Android Studio*

Comment: это старая библиотека, лучше найти другую аналогичную. как [подключать библиотеки в Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345) (в версиях gradle 3+ вместо compile теперь используется implementation)

Comment: неудобно сделано, автор не дает бинарников скачать, а так же их не залил ни в какой репозиторий, надо самому их билдить. Вам надо скачать проект оттуда, потом импортировать проект в android studio (папку library, тип проекта aar, android library), а потом запустить build и появится папка с либой, а дальше по ссылке от @pavlofff. А еще лучше и вправду найти поновее библиотеку, последний коммит в этой 6 лет назад.